# How to create new service from existing service

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, mxd, arcgis-10.4

I have an existing ArcGIS 10.0 Server, and have just setup an ArcGIS 10.4 Server. How do I go about moving a particular service from 1.0 to 10.4. I can locate the related mxd file as well as the SQL SDE database, but aside from that I don't know where any other data files are.

I am a developer who has been elected to do this admin side of GIS without any prior knowledge.

I really don't know where to begin aside from calling up ESRI and saying "help me".

Comment: The good news is that you have the most important piece: the mxd. Open the mxd in arcgis Desktop (arcmap) and publish to the upgraded server. It will not be as easy as it sounds, but that is the best way

Answer (score 1):

The MXD file's layer seemed to have something wrong with it so I couldn't simply just publish it. Also doing that didn't allow me edit some information regarding the layers. I ended up finding a gdb file which allowed me to add the layers and edit them as I saw fit.

Comment: Well that is a whole other question. Usually repointing the layers in the mxd to the correct data source resolves display errors, though it is not uncommon of mxds to have 'issues'. Good luck!